# .htaccess remove index.php and hide parameter name

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following URL

`www.site.com/index.php?key=blah`

I want to make it like the following using .htaccess

`www.site.com/blah`

How can i achieve this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: will you use just for `key` value or something else?

Comment: only for key parameter and only for index page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Does your index.php reside in some sub dir rather than on DOCUMENT_ROOT. Tell me more about your directory structure. Give this line a try: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

it is what i'm using on my website, it works on local too.

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?key=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```